# React useEffect() Infinite loop with firebase and react-router

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I've seen some answers say that to run useEffect only once, you have to give an empty list as second argument. This is my code

```
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hi')
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user)
        history.push('/')
    })
  },[])
```

First the linter tells me that **'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'history'. Either include it or remove the dependency array'**. I don't understand this because history is already removed since second argument is an empty array.

Second console logs hi infinitely. Why?

Comment: what do you have at '/' and what is the current url of the code you are trying to run?

Comment: @Oo-_-oO an empty page at '/'. current url: '/test'. Im trying to `if not auth redirect` logic

Comment: Something in your code is causing your component to unmount and mount again, which causes the useEffect to run again, and again... I'm not familiar with firebase, but if you can post more code or fully reproduce the issue, I will try to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a use effect hook only once if it uses a dependancy. Every time the dependancy changes it will force the hook to re-run.

You have to add history to the dependancy list because you are using the push method on history inside useEffect. This is non-negotiable.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hi')
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user)
        history.push('/')
    })
  },[history])
```

You will have to switch back to classes and use the componentDidMount method if you want to fire a function with dependency only once.